# Can I use Yaml based files in frontend (browser)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, browser, yaml

I'm trying to use yaml-based files as resources for i18next in my react project,
is there is any way to do that without using packages such as js-yaml...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only i18next-fs-backend has this in-built: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-fs-backend